# Why is jest test not recognizing react native components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a react native app that I am trying to run tests on, I have set up a basic greeting component as shown below called Greetings.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Greetings = ({hello}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{hello}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Greetings;
```

This is the test I am running called Greetings.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Greetings from './Greetings';

describe('Greetings component', () => {
  it('renders hello world as a test', () => {
    render(<Greetings hello="Hello World!" />);

    const helloWorldElement = screen.getByText('Hello World!');
    expect(helloWorldElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

For some reason it doesnt recognise the react native components, this is the error when running the test:

```
 FAIL  app/__tests__/components/Account/Greetings.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error
      Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You li
forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
      
      Check the render method of `Greetings`.
          at Greetings (C:\Users\meeve\OneDrive\Desktop\Cozify\smartliving-app\app\__tests__\components\Account\Greetings.js:4:21)

       5 |   return (
       6 |     <View>
    >  7 |       <Text>{hello}</Text>
         |       ^
       8 |     </View>
       9 |   );
      10 | };

      at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:220:30)
      at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:196:5)
      at Object.createElementWithValidation [as createElement] (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2215:7)
      at Greetings (app/__tests__/components/Account/Greetings.js:7:7)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6016:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8744:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9966:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13800:12)
```

It shows the same error for the View Component.
Should it not automatically recognize these components after initial setup?
I have installed the following:
yarn add install -dev react-test-renderer@17.0.1 @testing-library/react-native @testing-library/jest-native

The current Jest configuration in the package.json file:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "app/**/selectors.{js,ts,tsx}": {
        "_comment": "Let's strive to increase coverage, instead of lowering it!",
        "lines": 57
      }
    },
    "coverageDirectory": ".coverage/",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "native"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application was set up a while back and it seems they had mocked out the react-native imports in the jest.setup.js file so that was causing the issue

Comment: Great that it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Seems nothing wrong with the component rendering but the test.

You can use [`getByText`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api-queries#bytext) query which can be obtained from [`render`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api#render).

Please refer to [React Native Testing Library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/) for more information.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Greetings from './Greetings';

describe('Greetings component', () => {
  it('renders hello world as a test', () => {

   const {getByText} = render(<Greetings hello="Hello World!" />);

   expect(getByText('Hello World!')).toBeDefined();
 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Tank, Ive tried it with the getByText query obtained from render but it still gives the same error. Do you think it might have something to do with the jest configuration in the package.json file?

Comment: I added the current Jest configuration to the original question